# need right-to-left slide back button all the time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

For example,

I have three pages,
index, foo, and bar.

Clicking links like,
index => foo => index => bar => index

Then clicking back button,
index => bar => index => ...

When going back to bar, it acts with right-to-left slide correctly.
but when going back to index from bar, it acts with left-to-right slide like forwarding not backing.

How can I modify this to have all right-to-left slide by clicking back button?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding the attribute `data-direction="reverse"` to the anchor tags?

This is documented in the jQuery Mobile demo documentation, under 'Back linking'.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html